# Make custom animation on Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, animation, mobile

i want to ask you how can i create this animation on flutter for the onBoarding Screen.
[image of animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm02N.gif)

i tried to create it with onBoarding Widget but ti is just for images didn't find a solution to create the animation maybe cause i'm new with flutter animation

Comment: user Lottie animation onboarding screen

Comment: That looks like a tabview with a transition animation.